# Конфликт между командами бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу телеграм бота.Он имеет команды: погода и курс валют, когда я хочу вызвать два раза валюту отвечает функция погоды.Думаю, что это связанно с message.text.Не знаю как исправить, заранее благодарю за решение.Код:

```
import telebot
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from pycbrf import ExchangeRates

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
api_weather = ''
api_telegram = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot(api_telegram)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чем вам помочь?')
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['currency'])
def currency(message):
  markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
  item1 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('EUR')
  item2 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('USD')
  markup.add(item1, item2)
  bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="<b>Какой курс валюты вас интересует?</b>", reply_markup=markup,
                   parse_mode="html")
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, exchange_rate)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['USD', 'EUR'])
def exchange_rate(message):
  message_norm = message.text.strip().lower()
  if message_norm in ['usd', 'eur']:
      rates = ExchangeRates(datetime.now())
      bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                       text=f"<b>Сейчас курс: {message_norm.upper()} = {float(rates[message_norm.upper()].rate)}</b>",
                       parse_mode="html")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def weather(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чтобы узнать погоду напишите в чат название города')
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, test)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def test(message):
  city_name = message.text

  try:
      params = {'APPID': api_weather, 'q': city_name, 'units': 'metric', 'lang': 'ru'}
      result = requests.get(url, params=params)
      weather = result.json()

      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "В городе " + str(weather["name"]) + " температура: " + str(
          int(weather["main"]['temp'])) + "\n" +
                       "Описание: " + str(weather['weather'][0]["description"]) + "\n")

  except:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Город " + city_name + " не найден")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Я не очень знаком с python, но кажется есть различия в коде: `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "В городе " ` и в первой функции-конвертера `bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,` получается что `chat_id=` там лишняя или что?

Comment: Нет, ошибка не в этом.Я думаю она связана с тем, что функции test() используется     city_name = message.text, а в функция exchange() :  rate message_norm = message.text.strip().lower()

Answer (score 1):

Не требуется указывать `handler` если вы используете `bot.register_next_step_handler`.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['currency'])
def currency(message):
    markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('EUR')
    item2 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('USD')
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="<b>Какой курс валюты вас интересует?</b>", reply_markup=markup,
                     parse_mode="html")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, exchange_rate)


def exchange_rate(message):
    message_norm = message.text.strip().lower()
    if message_norm in ['usd', 'eur']:
        rates = ExchangeRates(datetime.now())
        bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                         text=f"<b>Сейчас курс: {message_norm.upper()} = {float(rates[message_norm.upper()].rate)}</b>",
                         parse_mode="html")
```

--

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def weather(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чтобы узнать погоду напишите в чат название города')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, test)


def test(message):
    try:
        params = {'APPID': api_weather, 'q': message.text, 'units': 'metric', 'lang': 'ru'}
        result = requests.get(url, params=params)
        weather = result.json()

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "В городе " + str(weather["name"]) + " температура: " + str(
            int(weather["main"]['temp'])) + "\n" +
                         "Описание: " + str(weather['weather'][0]["description"]) + "\n")

    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Город " + message.text + " не найден")
```

--

Однако вам потребуется `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`:

*пример грубоват*

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    if message.text in ('USD', 'EUR'):
        exchange_rate(message)
    else:
        print('else')
        # если сообщение буквы и длина больше 2 символов вызываем test(message)
```